Define Beam SQL UDF with complex data types
I want to write a user defined function that can be used in Beam SQL. At the moment I am defining UDFs (in Scala) by extending the BeamSqlUdf interface and overriding it's eval method. This works fine for simple types, and arrays. But I can't write an UDF that accepts or returns a nested row. My best guess was to use org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row
For example:
class GetNestedRow extends BeamSqlUdf {
  def eval(): Row = Row
    .withSchema(Schema.of(Schema.Field.of("name", Schema.FieldType.STRING), Schema.Field.of("age", Schema.FieldType.INT64)))
    .addValue("Alice").addValue(22L)
    .build
}

When I apply the SQL transform with the registered udf and this query: SELECT get_nested_row_udf() FROM PCOLLECTION I face

Cannot find a matching Beam FieldType for Calcite type: OTHER

for both Calcite and Zeta SQL.
What Java data type should be used for such cases?

looks like you need TableProvider.
